# Non-static method error in registering user

Tags: database, sqlite, registration

Here is my [registration class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvvi5.png) where am trying to add user into the database. However, having an error with static and non-static methods. 
If I make my .addUser static then the .getWritableDatabase() shows error.

How do i work around it?

Here is the addUser method in DatabaseHelper class:

```
public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_NAME, user.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());

    db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an Instance of the **DatabaseHelper** class and use the non-static method.

e.g.

```
public Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper; //Declare the DatabaseHelper object

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this); //<<<< Instantiate mDBHelper
        .........

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ........
            } else {
                mDBHelper.adduser(user); //<<<< Use the DatabaseHelper instance 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: aaah! i c! thank u! am still confused by all the language and coding, and static non-static...